# how to connect Azure SQL through Azure data factory both are hosted on different resource group

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect Azure SQL through Azure data factory both are hosted on different resource group.

I have tried to add the IP address for SQL firewall setup but struck with dynamic range.

Also got article for adding static IP ranges and given the try to look at the IP address ranges given in the Ms documents for East US 2, but found that my ADF instance generating different IP address than MS document given ranges. got struck here.

Can you please suggest here for the possible solutions. Appreciate all your efforts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ADF and Azure SQL database are hosted within the same tenant but different resource groups, Managed Identity authentication is the best security way.
Also w.r.t networking aspect,you can enable allow azure resources access in network property of Azure Server thereby avoiding whitelisting any IP ranges
[image]

Else corresponding to data factory region, you would have to whitelist the IP mentioned in doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/online-requirements

Comment: Thanks for your input Nandan.  I will check with Admin team and will try to implement it.